# Webspell CMS Movie Player bug

Tags: php, crossdomain.xml, movieplayer

I installed the Webspell template 4.2.3 on my website: www.insidious-horizon.de.

I put in a movie, you can go on movies and play it by yourself.

So the problem is that when I want to show it on the main page but on the bottom right on the site you can see an error message:

> task queue failed at step 5 playlist could not be loaded due to crossdomain policy restrictions.

I tried to install a movie plugin but this hasn't helped me.

EDIT: So I found out that u need a crossdomain.xml

My Crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
<allow-access-from domain="http://www.twitch.tv/" />
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

**cross-domain-policy: Least restrictive policy**

```
   <cross-domain-policy>
   <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
   <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

this might solve problem if not refer dev docs.

found this under adobe dev docs https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/xdomain.html